# About pthread-kill

Tags: pthreads, posix

I am using many pthread's . My program uses them and then, at a certain point I want to do a soft restart of my program, I am repeating "Soft-restart", not hard restart. By soft restart I mean, I will not exit the program,but, I start the program once more using "goto" statement, which points at the start of the program, to once again run the program.

My doubt is, if I am using the pthreads in my program and in the mid way, I get a soft-restart, then how do I kill my threads, I want to kill it by any means, as I don't require them.  Please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am using mutex, I have a q's in initializing. Please guide me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912930/i-am-using-mutex-i-have-a-qs-in-initializing-please-guide-me)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pthread_kill() to send the SIGKILL signal to the threads you want to stop.